# How to display custom theme's twig template on front page in Drupal 9?

Tags: php, drupal, themes

As you can see in the image, I have a following twig file under the custom theme and I cannot figure out how to display it in the UI (in local host) ideally in front page. Can this be done from the UI or do I need to write a function in `my_theme.theme` file (it is empty now). If it should be done from the `.theme` file then what type of function should I write?

More info: I have installed the theme and set it as default already. just want to see at least the `<div>testing</div>` on the front page.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can override template of the front page by creating `page--front.html.twig` file in your theme directory `my_theme/templates/`. Put some HTML code into it and flush the cache to see the change.